# Creating and removing border line on textFields

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, border

Actually i am trying to change border colour of each text field(By increasing border width) on tap.

I have given  textFieldEmailAddress.tag = 1    and   textFieldPassword.tag = 2 by using stotyBoard.

I am using UITextFieldDelegate.

Means my requirement is :-
 1. when i click on a text field its border colour should be dark blue(width =0.8)
and other text fields border line colour should be light blue (width = 0.4)

2. If we don't click on a text field its border line colour should be light blue.(width = 0.4).

But i am facing a problem when click on text field first time its working fine ,but just when i  tap on another text field ,its giving dark blue border colour.

problem is whaever textfield became 0.8 it's not reverting to 0.4 in UI (means UI is not updating only value is getting updated to 0.4)

Is any thing wrong in delegate method or in my below code :-

//View Did load function

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    //Set delegate 
    self.textFieldEmailAddress.delegate = self
    self.textFieldPassword.delegate = self

    //Create border line on text email address fields.
    self.borderline(textFieldEmailAddress)

    //Create border line on text password fields.
    self.borderline(textFieldPassword)

} 

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField)
{
    switch textField.tag
    {

    case 1:

        self.Darkborderline(textFieldEmailAddress)
        break

    case 2:

        self.Darkborderline(textFieldPassword)
        break

    default:
        break
    }
}



func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField)
{
    switch textField.tag
    {

    case 1:

        self.borderline(textFieldEmailAddress)
        break

    case 2:

        self.borderline(textFieldPassword)
        break

    default:
        break
    }
}
```

//Light blue Border line on text field.

```
func borderline(textField : UITextField)
{

    switch textField.tag
    {

    case 1:
            width =  CGFloat(0.40)

            let border = CALayer()
            border.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
            border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: textFieldEmailAddress.frame.size.height - width,
                                  width:  textFieldEmailAddress.frame.size.width, height: width)
            border.borderWidth = width
            textFieldEmailAddress.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None
            textFieldEmailAddress.layer.addSublayer(border)
            textFieldEmailAddress.layer.masksToBounds = true

            break

    case 2:

            width =  CGFloat(0.40)

            let border = CALayer()
            border.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
            border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: textFieldPassword.frame.size.height - width,
                                  width:  textFieldPassword.frame.size.width, height: width)
            border.borderWidth = width
            textFieldPassword.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None
            textFieldPassword.layer.addSublayer(border)
            textFieldPassword.layer.masksToBounds = true

            break

    default: break

    }
}
```

//Dark blue Border line on text field.

```
func Darkborderline(textField : UITextField)
{
    //let border = CALayer()

    switch textField.tag
    {
    case 1:
            width =  CGFloat(0.80)

            let border = CALayer()
            border.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
            border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: textFieldEmailAddress.frame.size.height - width,
                                  width:  textFieldEmailAddress.frame.size.width, height: width)
            border.borderWidth = width
            textFieldEmailAddress.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None
            textFieldEmailAddress.layer.addSublayer(border)
            textFieldEmailAddress.layer.masksToBounds = true

        break

    case 2:
            width =  CGFloat(0.80)

            let border = CALayer()
            border.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
            border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: textFieldPassword.frame.size.height - width,
                                  width:  textFieldPassword.frame.size.width, height: width)
            border.borderWidth = width
            textFieldPassword.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None
            textFieldPassword.layer.addSublayer(border)
            textFieldPassword.layer.masksToBounds = true

            break

    default: break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First declare one method to set bottom border to field and use the delegate method of `UITextFieldDelegate` like this

On `viewDidLoad` first assign thin border like this to both the fields

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.setBottomBorder(self.textFieldEmailAddress, width: 0.4)
    self.setBottomBorder(self.textFieldPassword, width: 0.4)
    self.setBottomBorder(self.passwordBtn, width: 0.4)
}

func setBottomBorder(view: UIView, width: CGFloat) {

    let border = CALayer()
    border.name = "BottomBorder"
    border.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
    border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.size.height - width,
        width: view.frame.size.width, height: width)
    border.borderWidth = width
    view.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None
    view.layer.addSublayer(border)
    view.layer.masksToBounds = true
}

func removeBottomBorder(view: UIView) {
    if let sublayers = view.layer.sublayers {
        for layer: CALayer in sublayers  {
            if layer.name == "BottomBorder" {
                layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
                break
            }
        }
    }
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    self.removeBottomBorder(textField)
    self.setBottomBorder(textField, width: 0.8)
    if (textFieldPassword == textField) {
        self.setBottomBorder(self.passwordBtn, width: 0.8)
    }
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    self.removeBottomBorder(textField)
    self.setBottomBorder(textField, width: 0.4)
    if (textFieldPassword == textField) {
        self.removeBottomBorder(self.passwordBtn)
        self.setBottomBorder(self.passwordBtn, width: 0.4)
    }
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true   
}
```

Comment: Ok let me check this once.
Thank you @Nirav

Comment: Have you try my answer?

Comment: Your code is working for left, right, bottom & top borders, but I want to apply on for Bottom border (Customisation)

Comment: i come just now sorry for late.
I will check and let you know .
Thank you

Comment: func setBottomBorder(textField: UITextField, width: width)


In your code i think here width is not predefined data type.
I think i have to CGFloat

Comment: Yes you need to use `CGFloat`, edited my answer for that.

Comment: Border line width is 0.8 in both case.

Comment: Are you sure you are passing width 0.4 with parameter?

Comment: Yes @Nirav 
I think UI is not updating .
Or in CALayer() something is missing,I don't know why.

Comment: @kishor0011 Check my latest edit and try to implement like that

Comment: You are genius.

But i have one more problem.
This code is working perfect for both text field but i have a button near to password text field, and i want to set border line for that also in the same manner.

I mean i have to set these functionality to button also.

Thanks Sir

Comment: Please put screen shot of your button problem explain some more.

Comment: Ok i will within 5 minutes.

Comment: Hi Sorry for late,
My requirement is now if i tapped on password text field (tag == 2 given to storyBoard) my button border line also be changed according to that text field.

I mean for button also i want to remove sublayer (CALayer() ),But those delegates methods are for only Text fields.

Comment: What if password textField resign than? What happen to button bottom border?

Comment: It is remaining same because ,

if let sublayers = textField.layer.sublayers {
            for layer: CALayer in sublayers  {
                if layer.name == "BottomBorder" {
                    layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
                }
            }
        }   


this method is for textField only.

Comment: I am asking you what if passwordfield resign then what is the width of button bottom border?

Comment: if passwordfield resign then  the width of button bottom border = 0.8

Comment: 0.8 or 0.4 because when passwordField resign its border is 0.4 and what color you want with button border same blue one?

Comment: Yes colour will be same  and Button border is 0.8 only.

Comment: When your textFieldPassword tap you want the button's bottom border width to 0.8 and blue color right? But i am asking when we resign this field it border goes to 0.4 width that same goes to button also?

Comment: we resign this field it border goes to 0.8

Comment: And when textField selected what is the width of border for button?

Comment: Actually very firstly I set the border width of button is 0.4.

After that  if i will tap password textField then button border width i want to be same as Password textField(0.8) and again i will resign this text field then border width should be 0.4.

But its not working like that

Comment: self.SetButtonBottomBorder(buttonEye, width: 0.4)

func SetButtonBottomBorder(button: UIButton, width: CGFloat)
    {
        
        let border = CALayer()
        border.name = "BottomBorder"
        border.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: button.frame.size.height - width,
                              width: button.frame.size.width, height: width)
        border.borderWidth = width
        //button.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None
        button.layer.addSublayer(border)
        button.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }

Comment: func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        if let sublayers = textField.layer.sublayers {
            for layer: CALayer in sublayers  {
                if layer.name == "BottomBorder" {
                    layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
                }
            }
        }
        if( 2 == textField.tag)
        {
            self.setBottomBorder(textField, width: 0.8)
            self.SetButtonBottomBorder(buttonEye, width: 0.8)
        }
            
        else{
            self.setBottomBorder(textField, width: 0.8)
        }
    }

Comment: Check my edited answer i have change method parameter with `UIView` and also add new for remove border check that

Comment: Ok Nirav i will try this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this once .

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool
{
    if 1 == textField.tag
    {
    selectedTextField = textFieldEmailAddress
    self.selectedTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
    self.selectedTextField.layer.borderWidth = 0.8
    self.selectedTextField = textField
    self.textFieldPassword.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
    self.textFieldPassword.layer.borderWidth = 0.4
    return true
    }

    else if 2 == textField.tag
    {
        selectedTextField = textFieldPassword
        self.selectedTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
        self.selectedTextField.layer.borderWidth = 0.8
        self.selectedTextField = textField
        self.textFieldEmailAddress.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
        self.textFieldEmailAddress.layer.borderWidth = 0.4
        return true
    }

    else
    {
        return false
    }
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool
{
    self.selectedTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
    self.selectedTextField.layer.borderWidth = 0.4
    self.selectedTextField = UITextField()
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true   
}
```

Comment: I need only bottom border line on text field.